# Can i use telephone api in PHP?

Tags: php

i need to know how can i connect telephone using php languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refer to the [Windows "TAPI" interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734273(VS.85).aspx), have a look at the [w32api PHP extension](http://www.php.net/w32api), which allows to call Win32 API functions from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot use php to connect through telephone lines. PHP is a scripting language. You can try out [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/). There are [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asterisk) about Asterisk dev in SO

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with [Erlang](http://erlang.org/) for this kind of stuff, since that is what the language originated from.

- [Erlang FAQ](http://erlang.org/faq/faq.html)
- [Erlang documentation](http://erlang.org/doc.html)

Comment: I initially down-voted this, but after reconsidering the question, I think you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Php theoretically provides the necessary features for that, but I don't know any library implementing any VOIP protocols. And I really doubt you want to do that: PHP has a veery slow interpreter and the language was not designed for that kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible. There are a couple of caveats though.

Php is platform independent but telephone api's arent. For example TAPI (the windows telephone api) is COM based and won't work on linux. There is probably a telephone api on linux too.

For TAPI programming in PHP you can look here:

https://www.php.net/com for information on using COM api's in PHP
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephony_Application_Programming_Interface information about TAPI

Answer (score 0):

[Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) is a web service that you can control with any language that you can host on a web server, including PHP. The question is unclear, but if you want to handle incoming and outgoing phone calls, they are a good solution.

[Tropo](http://tropo.com/) is a similar service that works with PHP too; slightly different model but still very easy to implement.